# Does auto increment affect when creating foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I'm using InnoDB and still learning about MYSQL. I'm trying to link songs to albums.
Is there something in my database causing the problem? Below is my tables.

```
Albums
•   albumID – int(11)
•   albumpic – varchar(255)
•   albumthpic – varchar(255)
•   albumTitle – varchar(255)
•   performer – varchar(255)
•   type – set (ex: ep, sp, studio)
•   titletrack – varchar(255)
•   genre
•   releasedate – date
•   distributor – varchar(255)
•   page – varchar(255)
Songs
•   songID – int(11)
 albumID - int(11)
•   albumpic – varchar(255)
•   tracknum – int(11)
•   songTitle – varchar(255)
•   performer – varchar(255)
•   album – varchar(255)
•   page – varchar(255)
```

Comment: albumID and songID is auto increment. I trying to create a foreign key but when I tried to link albumID (created in songs table), it isn't working.

Comment: `Is there something in my database causing the problem?` ... What is the problem?

Comment: Where is the foreign key column in the Songs table? I hope it's not the `album varchar(255)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for but if you are looking for how to create foriegn key and link to PK of master table then you can do like this:

```
create table Songs
(songID int(11) int not null auto_increment primary key,
albumpic varchar(255),
tracknum int(11),
songTitle varchar(255), 
performer varchar(255),
album varchar(255),
page varchar(255),
albumID int(11),
foreign key (albumID) references Albums (albumID) on delete cascade)
```

Comment: Edited ... typo mistake. Try now.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. I think I know why my table wasn't doing it. I had value in my default, would that had been the problem for not being able to link to PK? Since I noticed the table I create from the code you gave me had all null defaults.

Comment: Yes, cause I didn't mention `not null`. only PK is not null column. For Integer column you can have default value to be `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the default value from the columns with ones I put in and made it NULL. It worked!

Comment: @taeja87, if the answer helped you solve your issue then consider accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

One presumes that each song (optionally) belongs to an album; in which case, the `Songs` table needs a foreign key by which to reference the relevant record in the `Albums` table.  For example, you might add an `albumID` column:

```
ALTER TABLE Songs
  ADD COLUMN albumID int(11) [NOT] NULL,
  ADD INDEX (albumID),
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (albumID) REFERENCES Albums (albumID);
```

If individual songs might relate to multiple albums, you would need to create a third table which contains two foreign keys - that of a song, and that of its associated album (e.g. `songID` and `albumID`):

```
CREATE TABLE AlbumSongs (
  songID  int(11) NOT NULL,
  albumID int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (songID, albumID),
  INDEX (albumID),
  FOREIGN KEY (songID)  REFERENCES Songs  (songID),
  FOREIGN KEY (albumID) REFERENCES Albums (albumID)
);
```